# Calculate concentration of 10 µM to ng/ml Cannabidol

Tags: organic-chemistry, units

I would like to calculate the concentration of 10 µM unit in vitro to blood plasma unit ng/ml?

What formula do I need to use?

Do I need to use molecular weight? In my case, it is 314,47 g/mol for Cannabidiol

Can someone help?

Comment: You cannot be serious. I hope it is just a test question at high school level  and not a real lab task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10~ \mu$mol is $10^{-5}$ mol, and it weighs $\ce{10^{-5}}~ $mol · $314.47$ g/mol = $3.1447·10^{-3}$ g = $3.1447$ mg.

$1$ mL of this solution contains $3.1447~\mu$g cannabinol, which is also $3144.7$ ng.
So the concentration of your solution is $3144.7$ ng/mL

Comment: Be aware of proper taming of precision. 10.000 uM may mean 3144.7 ng/mL, but 10 uM does not. 3140 ng/mL is more than enough

Comment: @Poutnik. OK ! Let's admit $3140$ ng/mL, or even $\ce{3.1 10^2}$ ng/mL

Comment: You mean $\pu{3.1e3}$